# OS X asm C call with return value

Tags: c, macos, assembly, llvm, llvm-gcc

I've been playing around with the `asm` macro in C to directly call some assembly instructions on OS X Mavericks to get a stack pointer address (from %rsp) and I've found really strange behaviour (at least to me) while trying to assign a return value from the assembler code into the %rax register (the one that should by convention hold the function return value). The C code is very simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long get_sp(void) {
    asm ("mov %rsp, %rax");
    return 0;
}   

int main(void) {
    printf("0x%llx\n", get_sp());
}
```

If I compile and run the code, the value from %rax register gets printed(the actual stack pointer), which is strange as I would expect the %rax register to be overwritten by "return 0;"
However if I remove the `return 0;` a string "0x0" gets printed which is also strange as I would expect the return value from %rax register to be read and printed.

I've tried to run this code(with the only difference using %esp and %eax registers) also on the Ubuntu Linux also and it actually works as I would expect(using the gcc compiler).

Could this be a bug in the llvm-gcc compiler(Apple LLVM version 5.1)?

**//EDIT**
This is the version without the "return 0;"

otool -tV sp.out

```
sp.out:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_get_sp:
0000000100000f30    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000f31    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000f34    movq    %rsp, %rax
0000000100000f37    movq    -0x8(%rbp), %rax
0000000100000f3b    popq    %rbp
0000000100000f3c    ret
0000000100000f3d    nopl    (%rax)
_main:
0000000100000f40    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000f41    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000f44    subq    $0x10, %rsp
0000000100000f48    callq   _get_sp
0000000100000f4d    leaq    0x3a(%rip), %rdi ## literal pool for: "0x%llx
"
0000000100000f54    movq    %rax, %rsi
0000000100000f57    movb    $0x0, %al
0000000100000f59    callq   0x100000f6e ## symbol stub for: _printf
0000000100000f5e    movl    $0x0, %ecx
0000000100000f63    movl    %eax, -0x4(%rbp)
0000000100000f66    movl    %ecx, %eax
0000000100000f68    addq    $0x10, %rsp
0000000100000f6c    popq    %rbp
0000000100000f6d    ret
```

Comment: What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: Also, what is the output of "objdump -d a.out"?

Comment: Compiler flags were just -o sp.out... And I was playing with the lldb, so I've added also -g to get the assembly output.. I don't have objdump installed on my Mavericks... so I'm adding the output from otool -tV sp.out

Comment: I'm on Mavericks too, and the behavior is as expected when compiled with clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. It's the result of incorrect use of inline assembly. In the case where the return statement is included, the compiler does not inspect the asm statement. If `%rax` has already been set to zero before the asm block, the instruction overwrites that value. The compiler is free to do this *before* the asm block, since you haven't informed it of any register outputs, clobbers, etc.

In the case where no return statement is included, you can't rely on the return value. Which is why clang (that's what llvm-gcc is with Xcode 5.1 - it's not the gcc front end) issues a *warning*. gcc-4.8.2 appears to work on OS X - but because the code is incorrect in both cases, it's just 'luck'. With optimization: `-O2`, it no longer works. gcc doesn't issue a warning by default, which is a good reason to at least use `-Wall`.

```
{
    unsigned long long ret;
    __asm__ ("movq %rsp, %0" : "=r" (ret));
    return ret;
}
```

always works. `volatile` is not necessary, as the compiler is using an output, so it cannot discard the asm statement. Even changing the first line to `unsigned long long ret = 0;` - the compiler is obviously not free to reorder.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the explanation. Just one thing is still not really clear to me and that is why the "return 0;" statement does not overwrite the %rax value, when I do not compile with optimizations -O2.

Comment: @BranoH. - again, the compiler *might* have generated code to set `%rax` to zero at the start of the function, oblivious to what the asm stmt does. When the function returns, the compiler assumes that the `%rax` (return) value has not been modified. Alternatively, `main` might use an inline copy of `get_sp`. Even without optimization, the compiler can move things around, and apply 'as-if' transforms to the code.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me on Mavericks [edit: and without a single change on Ubuntu Saucy x86_64]:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long get_sp(void) {
    long _sp = 0x0L;

    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "mov %%rsp, %[value] \n\t"
            : [value] "=r" (_sp)
            :
            :);

    return _sp;
}       

int main(void) {
    printf("0x%llx\n", get_sp());
}
```

Comment: Yes, I agree that this works... but that's not the answer to my question. I'm actually wondering why on the OS X Mavericks using the llvm-gcc the return value gets read from the %rax register just in case when I add "return 0;" statement and why the "return 0;" does not overwrite the value of %rax register.

Comment: Apologize. I somehow thought this was obvious from the code. If you don't tell the compiler that you have a specific use for a specific register from inline assembly, its free to use it for its own purposes.
The fact it worked for you on one platform was just by accident (and basically just shows that two different platforms might have different compilers with different code generators).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. However, I've marked the answer of Brett Hale as the correct one as it is explained with more details.